# createRecordEvent.setParams is not populating values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to auto-populate the 2 fields in `Account` record during the creation of itself.
But for `LongTextField__c` field it's working fine but for `Amount` it's not reflecting the value in `Account` record. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks

```
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    'entityApiName': 'Account',
    'defaultFieldValues': {
        'RichTextField__c' : accountList,
        'Amount__c' : 12334.56
        },
    'recordTypeId' : recordtypeNameVar
});
```

Comment: have you tried to use 12334,56 instead of 12334.56?

Comment: but i want to save values with decimal , will it come as decimal in currency ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, probably you could provide error that you are receiving?

Comment: Hi Patlatus, I am not getting any error its just not populating the value of Amount (Currency field) on Account record.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard [Account field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) named Amount. I presume you're using a custom field, so you'd state so in your defaults:

```
Amount__c: 12334.56
```

Always make sure you verify if a field is standard or custom field.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for reminding me that is a custom field but still its not populating the values on to the account. Is there any specific way to assign Decimal value to Currency in 'defaultFieldValues' ?